# SQL Sum Multiple values for that day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is my table

```
TIME                     Status
2012-11-15 8:30:00.000   "WAS_FLOW"
2012-11-15 9:00:00.000   "WAS_FLOW"
2012-11-15 10:30:00.000  "H2_FLOW"
2012-11-11 12:14:00.00   "O23HZ_FLOW"
2012-11-11 8:00.00.000   "AZ_FLOW"
2012-11-12 9:00.000      "BZ_FLOW"
```

I want my results to show:

```
TIME         "WAS FLOW"    
2012-11-11   0
2012-11-12   0
2012-11-15   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers here all had slight glitches.  Here is one that I hope will work *straight out of the box* for you.

```
SELECT
  DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [time]), 0)             AS [date],
  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'WAS_FLOW' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS [count]
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [time]), 0)
```

Comment: I get this error  "The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value".

Comment: Why are you storing the time as a string!?  I strongly advise storing it as a DATETIME data type.  If you can't then you can use `LEFT(time, 10)` instead of the `DATEADD` calculations.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CAST(TIME AS date) AS TIME,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 'WAS_FLOW' THEN Status END) AS 'WAS_FLOW'
FROM dbo.your_table
GROUP BY CAST(TIME AS date)
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9db8/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.TIME, 101),
          CASE b.COUNT WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE b.COUNT END AS "WAS FLOW"
   FROM MyTable AS a 
       LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT Count(STATUS) AS "COUNT"
             FROM MyTable
             WHERE Status = 'WAS_FLOW'
             GROUP BY Time
            ) AS b
   ON a.TIME= b.TIME;
```

Comment: This won't include the output rows with a result of 0, instead those rows will simply not appear.

Comment: Also how do I Get the sum status for eaach day

Comment: @user1836442: Updated the answer. Please check and let me know, if doesn't help.

Comment: I think you need to say SELECT time, Count(STATUS) AS "COUNT"

Comment: 2012-11-11 9:00.000     NULL
2012-11-12 8:00.00.000 NULL
2012-11-15 10:30:00.000 NULL
2012-11-15 12:14:00.00 NULL
2012-11-15 8:30:00.000 1
2012-11-15 9:00:00.000 1